# how to plot MSE for LMS algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

would you please tell me how to plot MSE curve for LMS algorithm of the matlab code below. Thanks in advance.

```
clc
close all
clear all
N=input('length of sequence N = '); % filter length
t=[0:N-1]; 
w0=0.001;  phi=0.1;
d=sin(2*pi*[1:N]*w0+phi); %desired signal 
x=d+randn(1,N)*0.5; % input of the filter
w=zeros(1,N); %initial weight 
mu=input('mu = '); % alpha
for i=1:N
    e(i) = d(i) - w(i)' * x(i);  %error (desired-real output)
    w(i+1) = w(i) + mu * e(i) * x(i); % weight update of the filter
end
for i=1:N
    yd(i) = sum(w(i)' * x(i));
end
subplot(221),plot(t,d),ylabel('Desired Signal'),
subplot(222),plot(t,x),ylabel('Input Signal+Noise'),
subplot(223),plot(t,e),ylabel('Error'),
subplot(224),plot(t,yd),ylabel('Adaptive Desired output');
end
```

Comment: Can you please: 1) format your code properly, 2) explain what MSE and LMS are.

Comment: LMS is Least mean square. MSE is Mean square Error

Comment: Sorry man but I'm new here and I don't Know how to format my code. If you have any question about the code itself, I guess I can answer it. Thanks.

Comment: I did it. Thanks @ Ander Biguri

Comment: Please, check my update (in the comment below my answer). Also, very importantly, take the tour to the webpage to understand how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) consist in computing the sum of square differences between the desired and obtained result, and averaging it over number of samples. Thus:

```
MSE=sum((d(:)-yd(:)).^2)./size(d,2);
```

You can replace `size(d,2)` by `N` in your case

Comment: @Rock, you can replace the whole `size(d,2)` by `N` , not `d` by `N`! if you want to compute the MSE for each iteration, then you need to save it as `MSE(i)`

Comment: @Rock no worries ;) keep up with the work and come whenever you want! (but try to be more careful next time ;) )

Answer (score 1):

first you have to calculate the cost function like

```
J(n) = e(n)*e(n)';
```

and then plot the

```
MSE=10*log10(mean(J,1));
```